# foreach is saving only the first array even print_r printing the result correctly what am missing

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I am building a function to download images from an external source, and then write the id of each product has been downloaded along with the path to json file,

The download loop is working correctly but when am trying to save the product id & image path to a text file only the first record is saved.

i tried to print the output before using the `file_put_contents` function and it turns out am getting the correct result. I am wondering why only the first result is saved not all of them ?

I spent almost all day tryinf to figure it out but no luck. any help will be appreciated.

here is my code:

```
            $url = 'product-test2.json'; // path to  JSON file
            $data = file_get_contents($url);
            $characters = json_decode($data, true); 
            $i = array_column ($characters , 'Id');

            foreach ( $i as $value => $productid){
            include 'login.php';
            $url = "http://xxxx.com/api/products/image/";
            $url .= implode($matches [0]); // get the token form login.php
            $url .= '/' . $productid ;    //product id 
            // echo $url . '<br>';
            $opts = array ('http' => array ( 
                         'methos' => 'GET',
                         'header' => 'Content-typpe: application/json',
                         )
            );
            $context = stream_context_create ($opts);
            $urlImage = file_get_contents ($url , false , $context);
            $urlImage = substr_replace ($urlImage , "",-1);
            $urlImage = substr ($urlImage , 1);
            $fopenpath = 'C:\\xampp\htdocs\\test\\api\\images\\'   ;
            $fopenpath .= $productid . '.jpg';        
            $fp = fopen ( $fopenpath, 'w');
            $c = curl_init ($urlImage);    
            curl_setopt ($c , CURLOPT_FILE , $fp);
            curl_setopt ($c , CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt ($c , CURLOPT_POST, false);
            curl_setopt ($c , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            $rawdata = curl_exec ($c);
            fwrite ($fp, $rawdata);
            fclose ($fp);
            //
            $result3= ["id" => $productid ,"image_path" => $fopenpath]  ; 


            $image_file = "images.json";
            $output = json_encode ($result3);   
                print_r ($output);
            file_put_contents ($image_file , $output );  


            };
```

and here is the result from print_r ($result3);

```
 {"id":2977,"image_path":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\api\\images\\2977.jpg"} {"id":2981,"image_path":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\api\\images\\2981.jpg"} {"id":3009,"image_path":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\api\\images\\3009.jpg"} {"id":3018,"image_path":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\api\\images\\3018.jpg"} {"id":11531,"image_path":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\api\\images\\11531.jpg"}
```

as you can see the Print_r is correct all what i want to do is to save the output into file and currently here is the result from file_put_contents only one array  :

```
{"id":11531,"image_path":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\api\\images\\11531.jpg"}
```

can you please help and tell me what am doing wrong i already spend a lot of time on this :)

Comment: `'methos'` is that a typo? that should be "method".

Comment: your saving inside the loop, so overwriting each time

Comment: @rtfm i tried  already to save it from outside the loop but am getting same result

Comment: because you overwrite the variable inside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file_put_contents is the same as opening, writing, and closing the file, which doesn't really make sense to do in a foreach loop. If you really want to use it, I think you could add the FILE_APPEND flag, which will stop it from overwriting itself over and over and over.

An alternative would be to fopen before the foreach loop with the 'a' flag, which will create the file then keep appending lines instead of wiping out the file contents every loop. (And fclose after the foreach.)

Comment: yes you are correct 100% thanks @SeeSamRun i just added FILE_APPEND  flag and it's working i will consider using fopen :)

Comment: @kashalo make a lot more senses to append the variable and write only ONCE

Comment: @rtfm thanks for the advice i will see try your solution :)